# Mempoi generates double sheet with same data

Tags: java, mysql, excel, apache-poi, mempoi

I want to generate an xlsx with 2 sheets, one for managers data and one for employes data.
All goes well, but when I open the file both sheets contain same data.

This is my code:

```
private PreparedStatement createStmt() {
    return conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM WORK_PEOPLE");
}


PreparedStatement prepStmtMan = createStmt();
PreparedStatement prepStmtEmp = createStmt();

File fileDest = new File(this.outReportFolder.getAbsolutePath(), "report_2019.xlsx");


MempoiSheet sheet1 = MempoiSheetBuilder.aMempoiSheet()
                    .withSheetName("Mans")
                    .withPrepStmt(prepStmtMan)
                    .build();

MempoiSheet sheet2 = MempoiSheetBuilder.aMempoiSheet()
                    .withSheetName("Emps")
                    .withPrepStmt(prepStmtEmp)
                    .build();

MempoiBuilder.aMemPOI()
                    .withDebug(true)
                    .withFile(fileDest)
                    .withAdjustColumnWidth(true)
                    .addMempoiSheet(sheet1)
                    .addMempoiSheet(sheet2)
                    .withStyleTemplate(new SummerStyleTemplate())
                    .build()
                    .prepareMempoiReportToByteArray()
                    .get();
```

Comment: Please post PreparedStatements creation code

Comment: You put the same data (`prepStmt`) in both of them ... You should have something like `mansPrepStmt` for `sheet1` and `empsPrepStmt` for `sheet2`

Comment: @ButiriDan I'm new to java, i followed your advices but it still not work, please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify to the DBMS what data to get through statements. Now you have one statement `"SELECT * FROM WORK_PEOPLE"` that retrieve all your `WORK_PEOPLE` data. But you want 2 sets of data (one for EMP and one for MAN), so you will need 2 statements.

Base on your database model, you should select the data for each sheet

**Example**

If the data for each sheet is in the same table and it is separated by a discriminator (`type` for this example)

```
PreparedStatement prepStmtMan = createStmt("EMP");
PreparedStatement prepStmtEmp = createStmt("MAN");

private PreparedStatement createStmt(String type) {
    // Create a statement that select data from the WORK_PEOPLE table by TYPE column
    PreparedStatement prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM WORK_PEOPLE WHERE TYPE = ?");

    // Set the specific TYPE to the statement
    prepStmt.setString(1, type);

    return prepStmt;
}
```

The above statements will be

- `SELECT * FROM WORK_PEOPLE WHERE TYPE = EMP` will provide all WORK_PEOPLE that have type EMP
- `SELECT * FROM WORK_PEOPLE WHERE TYPE = MAN` will provide all WORK_PEOPLE that have type MAN

For a better understand of [**Prepared Statements**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and also a basic **SQL** tutorial would be useful